# Comparing dereferenced map iterators (std::pairs): C2678

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, multimap, std-pair

Consider the following example code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  typedef std::pair<char, char> MyPair;
  typedef std::multimap<char, char> MyMap;
  typedef std::pair<MyMap::iterator, MyMap::iterator> MyRange;

  std::vector<MyPair> pairs;
  MyMap bigMapOfStuff;

  //... adding things to pairs

  auto pairsIter = pairs.begin();

  MyRange range = bigMapOfStuff.equal_range('a');

  //... range validation checking

  MyPair pair = *range.first;
  if(pair == *pairsIter) { //OK
    //...
  }

  if(*pairsIter == *range.first) { //C2678
  }

  pair = *pairsIter;
  if(*range.first == pair) { //C2678
    //...
  }

  if(*range.first == *pairsIter) { //C2678
    //...
  }

  if((MyPair)*range.first == *pairsIter) { //OK
    //...
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In the comparisons I have commented //C2678 - this refers to the Visual Studio 2010 error:

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Why does this error occur in these cases?

I understand that `pairsIter` is a `std::vector<MyPair>::iterator`, and `range.first` is a `MyMap::iterator`, *however*, my expectation is that **dereferencing** the iterator returns the type, in this case `std::pair<char, char>` for both iterators.

Why do I need to be explicit about it?

Comment: That's still not the complete error message; that also contains what `_Ty1` and `_Ty2` stand for in this particular case. If you had read this, it would have hinted at the solution.

Comment: @Angew Ah yes, that'll teach me to look at the output window more often when it comes to templates

Comment: Wouldnt it still be enough to set parenthesis around *pairsIter? this is like implicit cast and you directly can compare them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `std::multimap<char, char>::value_type` (which is also what dereferencing iterators gives you) is **not** `std::pair<char, char>`. It's `std::pair<const char, char>`. It's that way so that you can't modify the key of an item stored in the map, which could break the map's invariants.

If you assign (or cast) the result of the dereference to type `std::pair<char, char>`, the comparison works. If you try to compare the different pair types directly, you get the error.

You could solve this by casting, or by providing your own function (either an overload of `operator==` or a named function) for comparing the different types. Or, more generally, for comparing `std:pair<T, U>` and `std::pair<const T, U>`.